# Get SUM of two columns linked to same column in different table

Tags: sql, database

I have a table "Events" for users to add events with the following fields: 
EventID 
EventName 
EventSlot (--> slotID) 
EventSlotExtra (--> slotID) (optional) 
EventLimit 

And I have another table "Slots" 
SlotID (int) 
SlotTime (this is 9am-10am, 10am-11am, etc) 

 
I need to query both tables so I can get a total of people attending events per SlotTime. I know how to do this when only EventSlot is selected but not when EventSlotExtra is also selected. Can you help?

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Comment: Presumably you also have a table of attendees which links to Events in some fashion.  Or is the "total of people" derived in some other fashion?

Comment: Yes, I do. But it's not necessary for this operation as EventLimit is giving me the number of attendees that hypothetically will be attending each event.

Comment: What database (including version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is great, Thanks!!!

I've just modified the code as I was looking for sum of attendees and not number of events per slot but otherwise the code from Charles Bretagna helped me a lot! Thanks again!

```
SELECT     
s.SlotTime, s.SlotID, ISNULL(SUM(x.EventLimit), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(e.EventLimit), 0) 
AS PeopleLimit
FROM       
Slots AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS e ON e.EventSlot = s.SlotID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS x ON x.EventSlot1 = s.SlotID 
GROUP BY s.SlotTime, s.SlotID
ORDER BY s.SlotID;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select s.SlotTime, 
   Count(e.EventId) + Count(x.EventId) EventCount
From Slots s    
    Left Join Events e 
        On e.EventSlot = s.SlotId
    Left Join Events x
        On x.EventSlotExtra = x.SlotId 
Group By s.SlotTime
```